# How do identity server validate the token at API or when we use Authorize attribute?

Tags: authentication, access-token, identityserver4

I am using Identity server 4 as identity provider.

After getting the token for a successful login, we pass this token to the resource server.

My question is how does the Identity Server provider at the resource server end validate the submitted token ?

When I observed the traffic using fiddler I didn't see any request submitting the token to the provider to check.

Which means Identity Server provider at the resource server end itself is validating the token ?

Then why do we need to provide Authority when it is not checking against it?

How does the identity server provider at resource end make sure it is issued by a valid token provider ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JWT tokens` are self-contained, and do not need a round-trip to verify that they are still valid with each use ... they are valid so long as they haven't expired, **providing they haven't been tampered with** which only involves signature checking.

You can set your client up though to request `reference tokens` (and set up your API to accept them), and these tokens **will** involve a round-trip every time they are used. You have the ability then to revoke tokens, which you can't do with JWTs.

Comment: So how does that signature checking takes place? Are we required to maintain some key on resource server to verify the text against signature?

Comment: Identity Server discovery endpoint is what I was looking for because that has information regarding the public RSA key.

Comment: It should never be assumed that a token has not been tampered with

Comment: @SeanHaddy that's right, it should never be assumed it hasn't been tampered with - which is why I mentioned in my answer that this would need checking

Answer (score 13):

The resource server will not send the token over the wire to the identity provider to validate a token. This would incurr quite an overhead to your resource server.

Instead the resource server pulls down (and might cache) your identiy providers discovery document located at `{identityserverUrl}./well-known/openid-configuration`. This document contains materials that allow the resource server to validate the token within its own context. This is ofcourse assuming that the token is an access_token (`issuer`,`jwks_uri`)

If your resource server is using something like JwtBearerAuthentication middleware or IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation middleware, these things will do that for you.